# Why is RuntimeBinderException thrown when generic parameter is private?

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

When a method is called with a dynamic parameter of the form `Foo<Bar>`, a `RuntimeBinderException` is thrown when `Bar` is private. Why? (See comment in `Run` method of `Test1` below.)

```
public class Test1
{
    public void Run()
    {
        dynamic publicList = ListProvider.GetPublic();
        DoSomething(publicList);

        dynamic privateList = ListProvider.GetPrivate();
        DoSomething(privateList); // Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException
    }

    private void DoSomething<T>(List<T> list) { }

    static private class ListProvider
    {
        static public object GetPrivate() { return new List<A>(); }
        static public object GetPublic() { return new List<B>(); }

        private class A { }
        public class B { }
    }
}
```

To see why this is unreasonable/inconsistent, note that `Test2` below, does not use generics, and succeeds when dynamic parameter is private.

```
public class Test2
{
    public void Run()
    {
        dynamic publicItem = ItemProvider.GetPublic();
        DoSomething(publicItem);

        dynamic privateItem = ItemProvider.GetPrivate();
        DoSomething(privateItem); // No exception thrown
    }

    private void DoSomething<T>(T t) { }

    static private class ItemProvider
    {
        static public object GetPrivate() { return new A(); }
        static public object GetPublic() { return new B(); }

        private class A { }
        public class B { }
    }
}
```

Why would/should the use of generics affect the resolution of a dynamic parameter with respect to access modifiers?

Answer (score 0):

The two examples you mention are not truly inconsistent (reasonable is a different matter): In each case, the runtime binder attempts to set `T` equal to `object` when it is faced with `class A`. For the first example, a list of type `List<A>` cannot be cast to a `List<object>`, so an exception is thrown. In the second case, however, casting an object of type `A` to an `object` works fine, and no exception is thrown.

The first example can be made to run by changing the definition of `DoSomething` to

```
 private void DoSomething<T>(IReadOnlyList<T> list) { }
```

since an item of type `List<A>` *can* be cast to type `IReadOnlyList<object>`.

Your initial statement of the issue is not completely correct, however: The issue is not whether the type in question is private or not, but whether the code making the call with the dynamic parameter has access rights to that type. If you move the `Run` method inside the `ItemProvider` class (as a static method, and also make `DoSomething` static to allow `Run` access), both tests will work fine. Moving `DoSomething`, however, will not matter.

I ran into a different variation of this problem myself: The type in question was internal, not private, so the same exact code ran fine if it was located in the project where that class was defined, but not when it was located in a different project.

Comment: @Little Endian Oh, and thank you - your question was what made me realize the solution to my own problem.